# reinterpret_cast<int*>(char*) vs. static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(char*)) -- which to use?

Tags: c++, casting

When you've dynamically allocated a buffer of type `char *` and want to cast it to a particular type, should you use something like

```
reinterpret_cast<int *>(char *)
```

or something like

```
static_cast<int *>(static_cast<void *>(char *))
```

and why?

I'm personally tempted to use the latter, because to me, it's not really a "reinterpretation" of the data (rather just a mechanical way of allocating the buffer) and it doesn't look like it would be a source of bugs in the same way as a typical `reinterpret_cast` might be, but is this the correct intuition?

Comment: You shouldn't do this at all, as it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: KerrekSB: What is "this" referring to, exactly?

Comment: @KerrekSB: its completely defined and even used in the implementation of vector (at least in my sgi version).

Comment: Those two forms are exactly identical for standard-layout types. per `§5.2.10/7` (C++11)

Comment: The answers so far seem to treat this as an abstract problem. For a real world example, I run into this situation with sockets or reading data from a file sometimes. I read an array of unsigned char * but the data in the array is actually ints. In this case I want to "reinterpret" my array of unsigned chars as an array of ints. Isn't that exactly what reinterpret_cast is for?

Answer (score 4):

[According to Dave Abrahams](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/10/128016.php), using the chained `static_cast`s is the correct, standard way to coerce pointer types.

Personally, I use `reinterpret_cast` in these cases because I never have to deal with architectures that would do one thing with the chained `static_cast`s and a different thing with the single `reinterpret_cast`.